# Circular reference in value argument not supported angular-ui-calendar in IE8 and IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, calendar, angular-ui

Have a problem when using angular-ui-calendar.

I end up with a circular reference in value argument not supported when I change route from where the calendar is loaded.

In addition the console is shown error indexOf not supported when the calendar loads.

This error only occurs on IE8 and IE9

In my controller I have
    $scope.eventSources=[[{"start":"2014-03-07T00:00:00Z","title":"Ring Child Services"},   {"start":"2014-03-06T00:00:00Z","title":"Check Up On incident_2"}]];

and in the HTML template

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="col-sm-11 calendar" ng-model="eventSources">    </div>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: when you change routes, are you trying to do anything with the events? the arshaw fullcalendar v1 creates a circular reference to its own events. If not, then I suggest using older versions of uiCalendar just to see if they work. I know it used to work fine with IE, but I have not used IE in over a year, so I would not be surprised if it was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was caused by changing location using location.href instead of $location.path.

Not sure why location.href caused he problem but using $location.path resolves the issue.